# Pod creation fails even after specifying cpu requests in openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have created a resource quota like below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: compute-resources
spec:
  hard:
    requests.cpu: "900m"
```

Then in my deployment I specify resource requests as below.

```
spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx@sha256:189cce606b29fb2a33ebc2fcecfa8e33b0b99740da4737133cdbcee92f3aba0a
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: hello
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "500m"
```

Even after this , the pod creation fails with message -

```
Error creating deployer pod: pods "hello-1-deploy" is forbidden: failed quota: compute-resources: must specify requests.cpu
```

What am I doing wrong here ?  FYI, I am using the same namespace/project for both quota and pod.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please also specify the limits along with the requests? Its anyways a kubernetes best practise to specific the limits for the workloads (wondering if Openshift is enforcing this, but obviously the error is misleading).

If you have access to see the kube-apiserver logs, you can see if there are additional clues.

Answer (score 0):

As workaround try to setup default limits by enabling LimitRanger admission controller and setting it up e.g.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: cpu-limit-range
spec:
  limits:
  - default:
      memory: 256Mi
      cpu: 900m
    defaultRequest:
      cpu: 900m
      memory: 128Mi
    type: Container
```

Now if a Container is created in the default namespace, and the Container does not specify its own values for CPU request and CPU limit, the Container is given a default CPU limits of 125m and a default memory limit of 256Mi

Also, after setting up LimitRange, make sure you removed your deployment and there are no pods stuck in failed state.

If that won't help , it'll be interesting to see the output of:
`kubectl describe ResourceQuota -n mynamespace`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Set the `scopes` onto your `ResourceQuota` object. E.g.:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: compute-resources
spec:
  hard:
    requests.cpu: "900m" 
  scopes:
  - Terminating
```

According to the [Quota Scopes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/#quota-scopes) documentation, the `scopes` is optional. In my case, it worked nicely on OpenShift 4.6 without `scopes`, but OpenShift 4.8 had a `FailedCreate` event (as described by you), until I added the quota `scopes`.